# Left sidebar disappeared after adding an image to the header

Tags: html, css

My **left sidebar** disappeared after adding an image to the header!

Here is how it looks now: [image]

Normally the left sidebar is the same as the one on the right with the fruit things.  Does somebody know why this happened?

The image that I added is in the "headerimage" class. The HTML and CSS code are shown below.

Code HTML:

```
<body>

    <!-- HEADER -->

    <div class="header">
        <a href="Design.html"><img src="Logo Greenery.png" class="image"</a>
        <div class="headerimage"><img src="vegatbles.png" style=" width:200px; height:150px; /></div>
    </div>

        <!--LEFT-BAR-->
        <div class="left-side"></div>

            <!--NAV-BAR-->
            <div class="navbar-nav" style="text-align: center;">
                <!-- Navigatiebar met de links erin -->

                <button type="button"><a href="HtmlPage.html">Producten</a></button>
                <button type="button"><a href="#">Registreren</a></button>
                <button type="button"><a href="#">Over ons</a></button>
                <button type="button"><a href="#">Contact</a></button>

            </div>

                <!--RIGHT-BAR-->
                <div class="right-side"></div> 

                        <!--CONTENT-->
                    <div class="Content">

                        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Hoofdstuk 1</h1>


        <h3>Een digitale tekst, elektronische tekst of e-tekst bestaat in principe uit een code voor ieder teken (in tegenstelling tot een grafische weergave zoals bij een letter op papier, en in tegenstelling tot een klank), eventueel aangevuld met opmaakcodes. (De meest basale codes die geen zichtbare tekens representeren zijn die voor de spatie en de nieuwe regel.) Dit maakt efficiënte elektronische opslag mogelijk, bijvoorbeeld als een txt-, html-, doc- of pdf-bestand, of in een van de speciale formats voor e-boeken.

            Voordelen van een digitale tekst ten opzichte van een tekst op papier zijn (een en ander voor zover deze mogelijkheden niet zijn ingeperkt, zoals bij Digital Rights Management, en verder afhankelijk van het bestandstype en de software) de doorzoek-, bewerk-, kopieer- en verzendbaarheid (onder andere e-mail en sms), de geringe massa en het geringe volume van een gegevensdrager, de instelbaarheid van de lettergrootte met automatische aanpassing van de hoeveelheid tekst op een regel aan de scherm- of vensterbreedte zodat zo veel mogelijk tekst op een regel staat zonder dat horizontaal scrollen nodig is, en de mogelijkheid tot keuze van een lettertype.

            Een nadeel is dat een apparaat en software nodig zijn om een tekst te kunnen lezen (de codes worden daartoe terugvertaald naar de grafische weergave op een beeldscherm) of te annoteren/bewerken/schrijven.

            Een tussenvorm waarbij de voordelen gedeeltelijk van toepassing zijn is het als afbeelding opslaan van ingescande tekstpagina's. Dit wordt toegepast als de tekst oorspronkelijk op papier stond en het te veel werk is om de tekst te digitaliseren (eventueel met OCR), of als men de oorspronkelijke opmaak exact wil behouden. In het laatste geval wordt ook wel een combinatie. toegepast van digitalisatie ten behoeve van doorzoekbaarheid, maar weergave als afbeelding.

            Omzetting van digitale tekst naar tekst op papier gebeurt met een printer.</h3>

                                    </div>

                            <!--FOOTER-BAR-->
                            <div class="footer-side">

                            </div>
```

Code CSS:

```
 body {

 margin-left:240px;
 background-color:antiquewhite;


 }

 .header{

width: 1300px;
height: 154px;
background-color: green;
border-radius: 25px;

  }

.headerimage{

margin-right: 30px;
float: right;
}

 .navbar-nav {
background-color: tan;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: center;
height: 60px;
width: 1300px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-radius: 25px;



   }


 .left-side {

float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 1000px;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-right: 50px;
background-image: url('fruittest.png');
background-size: auto;
border-radius: 25px;




  }

 .right-side {

float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 1000px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 40px;
background-image: url('fruittest.png');
background-size: auto;
border-radius: 25px;



   }

 .footer-side{


height: 100px;
width: 1300px;
background-color:green;
text-align: center;
margin-top:1000px;


  }

  .content{



margin-top: -1000px;
margin-bottom: 200px;


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line:

```
<a href="Design.html"><img src="Logo Greenery.png" class="image"</a>
```

replace to

```
<a href="Design.html"><img src="Logo Greenery.png" class="image"></a>
```

Comment: I removed the DIV and it is now only a image it seems to work now i need it to float to the right...

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

css:

```
.imagee{

margin-right: 750px;

}
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- HEADER -->

    <div class="header">
        <a href="Design.html" class="imagee"><img src="Logo Greenery.png"/></a>
        <img src="vegatbles.png" style=" width:200px; height:150px; class="headerimage" />
    </div>
```